# jQuery Slider Giving Incorrect Value

Tags: jquery, slider

I'm very new to using jQuery so please excuse me if this question is ridiculous.

I have a jQuery slider that displays the value currently selected, out of 100. I now need to get the remainder so I can use that in a calculation later on.

The code I have shows both values but percent2 is often 1 or 2 numbers either side of what should be displayed, so percent1 would show as 100 and percent2 would show as 2.

The code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#percent_slider").slider({
            orientation: "horizontal",
            range: false,
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            value: 50,
            step: 1,
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                $("#percent1").text(ui.value);
                var percent2 = 100 - ($("#percent_slider").slider("value"));
                $("#percent2").text(percent2.toFixed(0));
            },
        });
    });
</script>
```

Is this the best way to find the value I want?

Comment: Can you show an ([SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)) [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or [similar](http://jsbin.com), demo showing what's going on?

Comment: Is this any use: http://jsbin.com/ofahew/edit#javascript,html,live

Comment: That's fascinating, it alternates between `ui.value + percent2` equalling `99` and `101`...weird.

Comment: In fact, sliding left (to decrease the value) causes it to return `99`, and sliding right (increasing the value) causes it to return `101`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, and I genuinely have little idea why, this works:

```
slide: function( event, ui ) {
    var sliderVal = ui.value,
        percent2 = 100-sliderVal;
    $( "#percent1" )
        .text(sliderVal);
    $("#percent2" )
        .text(percent2);

    console.log(sliderVal, percent2, sliderVal + percent2);
```

[JS Bin demo](http://jsbin.com/ofahew/2/).

I'm assuming, though I'm not entirely sure, that there was a time-delay between repeated evaluations of the `ui.value` variable, throughout the function; assigning that value to a variable seems to cancelled out the delay, or minimised it at least.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it! I've hazarded a *guess* at why it works, but...I'm really not sure that it should... =/ Still! I'm glad to have been of help, and thank *you* for the accept! =)

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's need to be prsed as a integer, seems this value is a string... use **parseInt()** like that:

```
   var percent2 = 100 - parseInt($("#percent_slider").slider("value"));
```

Comment: Thanks for this but unfortunately I still get the same results